# No horizontal scrollbar in flex layout when scroll amount is less than vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm attempting to place a scrollable area inside of a flex layout, but when I need both horizontal and vertical scrollbars on my nested box, the vertical scrollbar isn't being taken into account when determining a need for the horizontal scrollbar (and vice-versa).

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/mjkwbud4/

#### The setup

The `.fixed` div is given:

- A fixed width of 200px
- `overflow: auto`
- inner block content which is 200px wide, with a height greater than the outer container.

#### Expected outcome:

- A vertical scrollbar to appear, since the content's height is larger than will fit
- A horizontal scrollbar to appear, since the vertical scrollbar takes up space, meaning the inner content wouldn't fit either.

#### Actual outcome:

- A vertical scrollbar appears, and takes up some horizontal space
- A horizontal scrollbar does not appear, despite there not being enough.
- Using the mousewheel shows that you can indeed scroll side-to-side, even though overflow: auto considers there to be no need for scrolling.
- Changing overflow: auto to overflow: scroll shows both scrollbars being active.
- `$0.scrollWidth > $0.clientWidth` is true - this is the origin of my problem, I need to detect scrollbars with JS in this layout

The jsfiddle includes a flexible container as well. Dragging the window shows the horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear as soon as there's overflow.

I'm seeing this to varying degrees in most browsers, so maybe I'm not understanding something deliberate about the spec? How should I put overflowing, both x and y, content inside a flex layout?

When doing this with normal block elements I don't get this problem, and the vertical scrollbar is subtracted when showing/hiding the horizontal one. I want to be able to do this in flex so I can fill height.

Comment: You have `.big {flex: 1 0 500px;}`. This means it will have a `flex-basis` (width in your case) of at least 500px and will grow to accommodate content. Whenever you size the window so `.big`'s width is smaller than `500px`, a horizontal scrollbar appears. What's the problem? What browser are you testing with?

Comment: The problem is that if `.big`'s container is less than 500px, you should get a scrollbar, yes. But if that container also has a vertical scrollbar of e.g. 16px,  you should get a scrollbar when the container is less than 516px. But you don't, so the container's scrollWidth is greater than its clientWidth, yet no scrollbar appears. 

If things are done the other way, the horizontal scrollbar DOES work as I expect (and consistently with non-flex).

Edit: hit enter too soon.

Comment: Compare these screenshots.

When the width is in the range where it's less than the container, but more than the (container - scrollbar), I'd expect a horizontal scrollbar, but none appears. With `overflow: scroll` there's an active scrollbar, but with `overflow: auto` there's no visible scrollbar. How can that be?

[Width greater than (container width - scrollbar width) --> no horizontal scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fur8.png)
[Height greater than (container height - scrollbar height) --> yes vertical scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVxQa.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `display: flex` this weird layout break happens, not sure if there is a real fix for this but I have found that **adding some border fixes the problem**. So you can add a tiny transaprent border to your flex child class (`.big`), it won't affect much your layout and will fix your issue:

```
border: 1px solid transparent;
```

you can see it working here:

```css
.fixed, .flex { 
  overflow: auto;
}

.outer {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;  
}

.fixed {
  color: #fff;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #606dbc,
    #606dbc 10px,
    #465298 10px,
    #465298 20px
  );
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}

.flex {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
}

.flex .big {
  flex: 1 0 500px;
}

.big {
  width: 199px;
  height: 200px;
  
  /* Just need to add a tiny transparent border here */
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="fixed">
    <div class="big">This is a fixed width.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="big">This is a flexible area.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```